# Time breaks between methods vb .net

Tags: vb.net

I have written a process in vb.net, that writes multiple text files based on SQL queries. I would like to put a "time break" after or before each method to slow down the process. Maybe just like a minute or two. I feel as this might be the solution for the problem I'm having with the last method(text file). Ever once and awhile I will get an exception that says: "EXCEPTION CAPTURED: The process cannot access the file 'D:\ORG.TXT' because it is being used by another process.". My thinking is that the other methods might somehow be blocking this one from running. If anyone feels there might be a better solution let me know.

Comment: I read your question as "something happens between my methods that causes space-time continuum to misbehave". You did not show any code, so we can't help you much with this issue. What you want is called a delay. Inserting a delay in your code is NOT a good solution. Try to figure out why the problem happens, and fix the root cause.

Comment: I am not sure what is happening here, since @Mike Haff didn't include code... but I have had this happen with third party add ons doing work on files and reporting back to our application that they are done - while, in fact, they are still holding on to the file and preventing further processing.

Comment: If your code is structured in such a way where it is possible that two threads can attempt to write to the same file simultaneously then one possible solution is to use [SyncLock](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3a86s51t%28v=vs.100%29.aspx). Adding delays is a terrible idea as @Neolisk says and will likely cause you more problems than they apparently cure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

System.Threading.Thread.Sleep()

However, you could also build a recursive method that tries to access the file, and if it can't, sleeps then tries again.  You would need to stop it at some point so it doesn't go on and on forever.
(Psuedocode)

```
If trythefile()
     do stuff with the file
Else
    fail
End If

function trythefile()
   try
       attempts + 1
       access the file
       return true
   catch 
       sleep for a bit
       If attempts < 10 
          trythefile()
       Else
          return false
       End if
end function
```